# Residue theorem- proposition for $Res(\frac{a(z)}{b(z)})$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In complex analysis notes I saw the following argument:

Let $a,b$ be holomorphic s.t. $b(z_0)=0$, $b'(z_0)\neq 0$ and $a(z_0)\neq 0$, for some $z_0$, then:

$Res(\frac{a(z)}{b(z)}, z_0)=\frac{a(z_0)}{b'(z_0)}$.

I don't see where the assumption $a(z_0)\neq 0$ is used. Here how I proved it:

Since $z_0$ is a simple root for $b$, there exists an analytic function $g$ s.t. $b(z)=(z-z_0)g(z)$ and $g(z_0)\neq 0$.

Now, $g(z_0)=lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{b(z)-b(z_0)}{z-z_0}=b'(z_0)$. Therefore,

$Res(\frac{a(z)}{b(z)}, z_0)=\int_{\gamma}\frac{a(z)}{b(z)}dz=\int_{\gamma}\frac{\frac{a(z)}{g(z)}}{(z-z_0)}dz=\frac{a(z_0)}{g(z_0)}=\frac{a(z_0)}{b'(z_0)}$, where $\gamma$ is some circle around $z_0$ and the third equality is from Cauchy's Integral Formula.

What do I do wrong?

Thnks!

Comment: The assumption $a(z_0)\neq0$ is not necessary, as your proof shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a(z_0)\neq 0$ then $z_0$ may not be a pole of $\dfrac{a(z)}{b(z)}$ always.

Consider for example the function $\dfrac{z^2}{z}$.

Comment: But the formula still works... one gets 0, as expected for removable singularity, no? What does not work in the proof I wrote?

Comment: the function $\dfrac{z^2}{z}=z$ does not have a pole

Comment: so in order to make a useful theorem,the hypothesis is assumed in dis way

Comment: I agree that it is not useful without having a pole. My question is just if this still holds in this case

Comment: @Kiko Not having a pole is irrelevant for that formula. There is no claim in that theorem about the type of singularity of $a(z)/b(z)$. So, the fact that if $a(z_0)=0$ there is no pole doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to you both

Comment: @Kiko; if the function has no pole there is no question of residue

Comment: @Student Yes, I agree...I saw it also for removable singularities but then as you said, we get 0 and it is not relevant.

Comment: @Kiko;the residue is a complex number proportional to the contour integral of a meromorphic function along a path enclosing one of its singularities according to wiki

Comment: if it has no singularities the definition is more or less useless